# error about tensorflow.contrib.eager.metrics.Mean()

Tags: tensorflow

I am working through a tensorflow tutorial in Google Colabs and have run everything as the tutorial specifies in the link below:

https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/eager/custom_training_walkthrough

```
num_epochs = 201;

for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    epoch_loss_avg = tensorflow.contrib.eager.metrics.Mean();
    epoch_accuracy = tensorflow.contrib.eager.metrics.Accuracy();

    # Training loop - using batches of 32
    for x, y in data_set:
        # Optimize the model
        loss_value, grads = grad(model, x, y);
        optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, model.variables), global_step);

        # Track progress
        epoch_loss_avg(loss_value);
        # compare predicted label to actual label
        epoch_accuracy(tensorflow.argmax(model(x), axis=1, output_type=tensorflow.int32), y);

    # end epoch
    train_loss_results.append(epoch_loss_avg.result());
    train_accuracy_results.append(epoch_accuracy.result());
```

This code works OK， but if I rewrite it as below, I get a error like this:

Non-boolean tensor (tf.Tensor: id=201, shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=3.6846912) cannot be converted to boolean.

```
num_epochs = 201;

for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    #epoch_loss_avg = tensorflow.contrib.eager.metrics.Mean();
    #epoch_accuracy = tensorflow.contrib.eager.metrics.Accuracy();

    # Training loop - using batches of 32
    for x, y in data_set:
        # Optimize the model
        loss_value, grads = grad(model, x, y);
        optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, model.variables), global_step);

        # Track progress
        tensorflow.contrib.eager.metrics.Mean(loss_value);
        # compare predicted label to actual label
        tensorflow.contrib.eager.metrics.Accuracy(tensorflow.argmax(model(x), axis=1, output_type=tensorflow.int32), y);

    # end epoch
    train_loss_results.append(epoch_loss_avg.result());
    train_accuracy_results.append(epoch_accuracy.result());
```

What is the reason？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`epoch_loss_avg = tensorflow.contrib.eager.metrics.Mean()` creates an object that you can use to track mean, by calling it `epoch_loss_avg(loss_value)`.

But if you do this instead `tensorflow.contrib.eager.metrics.Mean(loss_value)`, you are trying to create a mean tracking object with a float tensor which it doesn't understand. See the `__init__` and `__call__` methods (docs and code) for [Mean](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/eager/metrics/Mean) to understand whats going on.

Also don't use semicolons in python :)

Comment: thanks for answer, I got it.
I am a c++ programmer,  I think python is so flexible that  hard to read sometimes, and over-packaging causes confusion.
using semicolon comes from C++ programming, I think it marks the end of the code clearly.